How do you turn off the bar on the left of Visual Studio indicating changes

This thing... when you click it, it shows you changes you've made, and I hate it! I accidentally click on it SOOOO many times when I'm just trying to select a whole line. I don't even know what the feature is called.
Stack Overflow is saying that my post is mostly images and I have to type more, so here's some lorem ipsum text.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

It's called the "Difference overview margin"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-advanced?view=vs-2022

